# For measuring a resistance should you use a constant current source or a voltage source?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, resistance, measurement

I need to design a PCB to measure a resistance of around 5 kΩ and a resistance of 0.2 Ω. I don't know what the best solution for measuring these resistances is; maybe a combination of both methods?

To actually measure current and voltage you can use a shunt resistor with an op-amp, and for only current you can use a Hall sensor.

Comment: What are your precision requirements?

Comment: Thanks for answering I can decide those myself , but I don't know what practical is; maybe 5%?

Comment: @LuukBenningshof Stop developing a solution until you've figured out your requirements.  Every solution is a tradeoff between cost, complexity, and precision.  If you don't know how precisely you need to measure something we cannot help in any meaningful way.

Comment: 5% sounds trivially achievable. 0.5% would start to get interesting. Don't forget the temperature compensation.

Answer (score 13):

It comes down to semantics.

To make a precise measurement of a low resistance, you must do a 4-wire measurement. For this you must know both the voltage drop across your resistor as well as the current running through it. You must make those two *measurements* either way.

The impedance of your power supply doesn't matter (aka "current source" or "voltage source") for the validity/accuracy of your measurement.

However, for practical reasons a voltage source is simpler to come by. Add a series resistor with it of about 100 Ohm to both limit and measure the current.

You can also consider whether a current/voltage source would be safer than the other in edge cases: E.g. a "current source" will be graceful in a short-circuit condition, but saturate in an open-circuit condition and source a large transient when contact is re-established. A "voltage source" will be also graceful in the short-circuit condition due to the aforementioned series resistor, but it will be also graceful in the open-circuit condition.

Comment: Thanks for answering, there are a couple things I don't understand. First how would you use a voltage source and current meter in a 4-wire configuration. Second if you add a series resistor of 100 ohm in series with it, you can't really measure that 0.2 ohm, because of the tolerances.

Comment: if you measure the current and the voltage across the resistor, then you'll get resistance. Do the math.

Comment: @LuukBenningshof The 100 Ω resistor can be of loose tolerance. But you have to measure it with an accurate meter once. Then you can plug the real value, e.g. 103.776 Ω into your math. If you use a 4.096 V source, roughly 8 mV would drop over your 0.2 Ω DUT and the rest over the 100 Ω resistor. For the 5 kΩ DUT, roughly 80 mV will drop on the 100 Ω resistor and the rest on the DUT. That is why would need probably two different gain settings for the two DUTs or sacrifice some precision using a single gain setting.

Comment: @LuukBenningshof *"how would you use a voltage source and current meter in a 4-wire configuration"*: You use a voltage source, a series resistor and two voltage probes to determine the voltage drop across the DUT and across the 100 Ω resistor.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to measure 0.2 Ω, then 4-wire is your only practical solution. This means a current source passing a current through the device under test, and a voltmeter measuring the voltage across it.

Once you have those two items, you only need to change the ranges to measure any resistance.

Comment: Thanks for answering but would that really make a difference if the testleads are PCB traces?

Comment: @LuukBenningshof Resistors lower than ~1k I would mesure with 4-Wires if you have to be precise (16*e10-6 R + 50 µΩ with HP3458 in the low Ohms Range)

Comment: PCB traces have a nonzero resistance.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a constant voltage source then your measurement will have the highest relative precision at the low end of the range of resistances.

If you use a constant current source then your measurement will have the highest relative precision at the high end of the range of resistance.

You should always measure both voltage and current, since it's nearly always possible to measure more accurately than you can source. Given the very small resistance involved I would also say a 4-wire connection to the resistance under test is in order.

To maximize the usable range of a single configuration, you want to use a source with an impedance around the geometric mean of the top and bottom of your measurement range.

If I was looking to measure resistances in the range you have specified without reconfiguration, I would be looking at a voltage source with a 30 ohm resistor in series, this resistor can double up as your shunt for current measurement.

Lets call the resistor under test \$R_t\$ and the source resistor \$R_s\$.

At the low end of the range a 5% change in R_t translates into a roughly 5% change in voltage across \$R_t\$ and a negligible change in the voltage across \$R_s\$. The voltage across \$R_t\$ is about 0.6% of full scale. So we need a measurment precision of about 0.03% of full scale voltage.

Similarly at the high end of the range, a 5% change in R_t translates into a roughly 5% change in voltage across \$R_s\$ and a negligible change in the voltage across \$R_t\$ .The voltage across \$R_s\$ is about 0.6% of full scale. So we need a measurment precision of about 0.03% of full scale voltage.

I'd say with 14 bit ADCs it should be more than practical to meet your requirements without the complexities of re-configuring the system for different resistance ranges.

It might be possible to do it with lower precision ADCs and averaging, but if you do then you have to make sure your system is sufficiently noisy.

Comment: Had the same idea, with the geometric mean after writing my answer. put the voltage source, then 5k, then 30R, then 0.2R to GND. that way one must only switch the voltage tap points and can use two fixed gain opamps to measure both values at highest precision.

Comment: That's not a bad idea if you need to measure both at once rather than having a circuit that can measure either of them but not at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still have some questions. Why does a voltage source the highest relative precision at the low end of the range of resistances.. It doesn't need to be a 4 -wire connection because its on a PCB.